# For date field type in salesforce wave analytics, internally many sub fields for date gets added. What can i do to get only the field that i provide?

Tags: date, einstein-analytics

For example i have a date type field as **ClosedDate** in the external CSV file that i need to upload to create a dataset, when i try to see the fields, internally many sub fields gets added as follows:

- ClosedDate_Year
- ClosedDate_Quarter
- ClosedDate_Month
- ClosedDate_Week
- ClosedDate_Day
- ClosedDate_Hour
- ClosedDate_Minute
- ClosedDate_Second

But i don't want other fields, i only want one field that is **ClosedDate** with format which i specified. How can i achieve this?